# Using Python and OpenCV split and record RTSP source into multiple files

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-streaming

I'm using OpenCV and RTSP source to continuously record video from the RTSP source for 1 minutes.
And then start the process again and create new one.
Recording works fine for a while and then the program would only create files that are 6kb in size that are not playable.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time


def get_output(out=None):
    #Specify the path and name of the video file as well as the encoding, fps and resolution
    if out:
        out.release()
    return cv2.VideoWriter(str(time.strftime('%d %m %Y - %H %M %S' )) + '.avi',   cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),
                             24, (320,240))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4")
next_time = time.time() + 60
out = get_output()

while True:
    if time.time() > next_time:
        next_time += 60
        out = get_output(out)

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read() 

    if ret:
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    # Break the loop
    else:
        break    

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: use ffmpeg (PyAV). OpenCV is for computer vision, not for moving or transcoding video data -- did you expect VideoWriter to resize the frames you give it? it does not do that.

Comment: I want to split the captured video by time interval . example 1 minute / 1 video

Comment: state the value of `frame.shape`. are you suggesting that `imshow` keeps showing you the stream? your description of the error is being vague there